# Vue.js ReferenceError in event payload

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a user profile page with an image. I'm uploading the image to Firebase Storage, updating the user's record in Firestore to point at the image and displaying it. I have everything working in a single component.

Now I want to refactor to put the image uploading functionality into its own component with the idea that the new component will return the url of the uploaded file so that the parent component can then update Firestore. The benefit being that I can re-use the image upload component on other pages without the uploader needing to know why it's uploading images. The way I have architected this is as follows:

```html
<template>
...
<v-btn 
    :disabled="!file" 
    class="primary" 
    small 
    @click.prevent="selected">Upload</v-btn>

...
</template>
```

```
export default {
  name: "BaseImageUploader",
  props: {
    accept: {
      type: String,
      default: () => "image/png, image/jpeg, image/bmp"
    },
    placeholder: {
      type: String,
      default: () => "Click to select an image to upload"
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: () => "Profile Picture"
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    file: null
  }),
  methods: {
    selected() {
      const fileRef = storage.child("corporate-wellness-1/" + this.file.name);

      fileRef
        .put(this.file)
        .then(uploadTaskSnapshot => uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL())
        .then(url => this.$root.$emit("base-image-uploader", url))

    }
  }
};
```

then the parent listens for the event and updates Firestore like so:

```js
...
mounted() {
    this.$root.$on(`base-image-uploader`, (event) => {
            this.uploadImage(event)
    });
},
...
uploadImage(url) {
    this.$store
        .dispatch("user/updateProfileImageUrl", url)
        .then(() => console.log('image url updated in bio'))
}
```

The problem is I'm getting

```js
ReferenceError: url is not defined
```

on the dispatch in the parent component.

The event only gets emitted after the url becomes available in the child component, so I don't understand why it's not available in the parent when the event handler is called.

So, I've two questions:

1. Why doesn't the code written work?
2. And more generally, is there a better way to architect it?